# how can I find the exceptions that my code isn't giving the right answer to

Tags: python, debugging, numbers

> we got a tv with 100 channels. The TV remote control consists of buttons from 0 to 9, _ (underscore), up, and down. The up and down buttons increase or decrease the TV channel by one. To go to a channel directly, if the channel number is two digits, we need to press the _ button first. For example, to go directly to channel 85, we need to press the buttons in the following order: _ 8 5. However, to go directly to channel 6, we only need to press the 6 button.
>
> in the first 4 lines of input we enter 1 as working buttons and 0 for broken buttons.
>
> Input:
> The first four lines of the input represent the status of the control buttons as shown below. (1 means working, and 0 means broken)
>
> ```
> 1 2 3 up
> 4 5 6 down
> 7 8 9 _
> 0 1
> ```
>
> next line contains two numbers X and Y representing the current channel and the desired channel, respectively.
>
> 0 ≤ X, Y ≤ 99
>
> Output:
> In a single line of output, print the minimum number of button presses needed to go from channel X to channel Y. If it is not possible to go to the specified channel, print -1.

this is the code I wrote for it expecting to get full mark:

```
a1 , a2 , a3 , aU =input().split(" ")
a4 , a5 , a6 , aD =input().split(" ")
a7 , a8 , a9 =input().split(" ")
a  , a0 =input().split(" ")
X , Y =input().split(" ")
a1 , a2 , a3 , a4, a5, a6, a7 , a8, a9 , a0 , aU, aD, a = map(int,(a1 , a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a0, aU, aD, a))
a1 , a2 , a3 , a4, a5, a6, a7 , a8, a9 , a0 , aU, aD, a = map(bool,(a1 , a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a0, aU, aD, a))
X , Y = int(X) , int(Y)
keys =  [False for i in range(100)]
keys[0:10]=map(bool,(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9))

currentNum10=0
if a:
    keys[0:10]=map(bool,(a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9))
    while currentNum10!=9:
        currentNum10+=1
        if keys[currentNum10]:
            currentNum=-1
            while currentNum!=9:
                currentNum+=1
                if keys[currentNum]:
                    keys[(currentNum10*10)+currentNum]=True

keys[X]=True
movesU=0
movesD=0
if aU:
    i=Y
    while i>=0:
        if keys[i]:
            if i==X:
                movesU=Y-i
                break
            elif i>=10: 
                movesU=3+Y-i
                break
            else: 
                movesU=1+Y-i
                break
        i-=1

if aD:
    i=Y
    while i<=99:
        if keys[i] :
            if i==X:
                movesD=i-Y
                break
            elif i>=10: 
                movesD=3+i-Y
                break
            else: 
                movesD=1+i-Y
                break
        i+=1


if movesD==0 and movesU!=0:
    if X<Y and Y-X<movesU:
        print(Y-X)
    else:
        print (movesU)
elif movesD!=0 and movesU==0:
    if X>Y and X-Y<movesD:
        print(X-Y)
    else:
        print (movesD)
elif movesD>=movesU and movesU!=0:
    print(movesU)
elif movesD<movesU:
    print(movesD)
elif X!=Y:
    print(-1)
else:
    print (0)
```

but the code above only got 70% of the full mark by giving a wrong output for 30% of the questions the platform its on tests, I have tried to find every possibility that might give a wrong output but couldnt find any and still think it should be full mark. can you help me with it?

code explanation:
after taking the inputs, we make an array of booleans that we can directly go to using the working numbers, after that we check which ones we can use to get to the destination with up and down if it wasnt possible to directly go to it. then i compare directly trying reaching the number with Up and Down and if the path is shorter than using numbers we output that and else.

would really love if someone reads my code and helps me find the problem and potentially fix it.

Comment: The description of the first 4 lines of input doesn't match what you're parsing: 1) You seem to be missing the state of the `_` button; 2) the input shows 14 total values but you're only reading 13; 3) `1` is represented twice

Comment: if you have multiple nested loops, you might wish to watch this:
[flatten nested loops](https://youtu.be/eJP8OSFZrJY)